# Reading I2C bytes on Beaglebone Black

Tags: python, i2c, beagleboneblack

I've got a Beaglebone Black running Linux beaglebone 4.14.71-ti-r80 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 5 23:50:11 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

I've got an ams iAQ-Core CO2 sensor attached to the I2C bus, datasheet: https://datasheet.octopart.com/IAQ-CORE-C-ams-datasheet-44382459.pdf

Beaglebone finds the sensor on address 0x5A when doing

`i2cdetect -y -r 2`

I was reading the datasheet and didn't immediately know what to do next. Basically I would like to read the 9 bytes containing CO2, TVOC, resistance and status info.

Ideally I would like to do this in Python (2.7 or 3), was looking at Adafruit_GPIO library but the documentation and examples is a bit lacking and I could not get it to read the 9 bytes.

What library should I use and what do I need to do to get these 9 bytes out? Looking at the datasheet, they say something about 'Communication with the sensor starts with the 0xB5 for reading data', does this mean I need to send 0xB5 on the wire?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many different [tutorials](https://www.teachmemicro.com/beaglebone-black-i2c-tutorial/) how to deal with I2C using Beaglebone Black.

Comment: @Qiu Yes I've googled as well, but many are outdated or using libraries that are tagged deprecated. The one you've linked to is not using Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028083/how-to-get-data-from-i2c-device-bh1750-over-usb-i2c-module-in-python3