# Android FTDI to I2C

Tags: java, android, usb, i2c, ftdi

I have an android application that is connected to a USB hub which has a FDTI chip which is connected to an I2C. 
I want to communicate with the I2C (read/write) and I have the address of the I2C.

I am using the d2xx library and have my FT_Device but the 'write' functions for an FT_Device do not include one for writing to a specific address.
Does anyone know how i can write and read to a specific I2C address? (I am new to USB communication so sorry if this is a basic question)

Comment: I dont know which llibrary you are exactly using. The MPSSE library provided by FTDI has a I2C_DeviceWrite function which allows to specify the addresse as parameter. Chances are that your library pass it as part of the data stream (the i2c address is "simply" put in front of the write together with the last bit determining if its a read or write request).

Comment: @ChristianB. I couldn't find the MPSSE library for android on the site?

Comment: Well there is https://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm - however I am not sure that they match your needs 100% - actually it can be that you have to write your own MPSSE-I2C library for android. Basically it sends command to the FT device which makes it act like a I2C. Not sure if your device is actually supported anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028083/how-to-get-data-from-i2c-device-bh1750-over-usb-i2c-module-in-python3