# Sysfs doesn't recognize any GPIO chip - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, gpio, acpi, libgpiod

I am trying to set GPIOs of an embedded Mini PC with Ubuntu 18.04 as inputs or outputs for handling several sub-projects. My PC is the [Supermicro SYS E100-9W-E](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/system/Box_PC/SYS-E100-9W-E.cfm), it provides 1x 8-bit GPIO via the DB9. The kernel version of the system is 5.4.0-74-generic. I have read a lot about sysfs and character device nowadays, and in the past, I had an experience with the GPIOs of the Raspberry Pi. In my system, I am unable to find any gpiochip:

```
root@SYS:~# ls -l /sys/class/gpio/
total 0
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jun 15 14:29 export
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jun 15 12:16 unexport
```

Also, there is nothing at the chardev interface (such as /dev/gpiochip0) and nothing to the /sys/kernel/debug/gpio. `libgpiod` couldn't detect any chip, too. Moreover, there is nothing to configure at the BIOS menu, such as presetting I/O pins as input or output. The following quote is the only thing I could find in the MOBO/PC manuals:

> General Purpose I/O Header: The JGP1 (General Purpose Input/Output)
> header is a general purpose I/O expander on a pin header via the
> SMBus. Each pin can be configured to be an input pin or output pin.
> The GPIO is controlled via the PCA9554APW 8-bit GPIO expansion from
> PCH SMBus. The base address is 0xF040. The expander slave address is
> 0x4C for WRITE and READ. Refer to the table below for pin definitions.
>
> Pin - Definition
>
> - 1 - P3V3SB
> - 2 - GND
> - 3 - GP_P3V3_GP0
> - 4 - GP_P3V3_GP4
> - 5 - GP_P3V3_GP1
> - 6 - GP_P3V3_GP5
> - 7 - GP_P3V3_GP2
> - 8 - GP_P3V3_GP6
> - 9 - GP_P3V3_GP3
> - 10 - GP_P3V3_GP7

I tried also to echo several numbers at the export file at the /sys/class/gpio but nothing happened.

Do you have any suggestions about the kernel configuration or the Driver that I should follow?

Comment: Have you enabled `gpio-pca953xx` driver? Does your platform description have the reference to this IO expander? Meanwhile read also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727454/how-to-configure-acpi-asl-for-a-virtual-mdio-gpio-device-connected-to-a-i2c-gp/, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105101/diolan-dln-2-spi-controller-on-x86-64-platform/, and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64/.

Comment: Can you share the file _table.dat_ after running `acpidump -o table.dat`.