# Modify devicetree driver style base for x86_64 PC

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree, acpi

As I know, Device Tree driver style was for SoC, not for x86_64 platform.

However, if I want to use an already available driver but it is probed by devicetree, such as below.

Due to it is running x86_64 PC Ubuntu 20.04, and disable devicetree feature by default.
Is any experience, suggestion here?

```c
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(spi, xxx_spi_id);

static struct spi_driver xxx_spi_driver = {
        .driver = {
                .name   = XXXSPI_DRV_NAME,
                .of_match_table = xxx_spi_of_match,
        },
        .id_table = xxx_spi_id,
        .probe    = xxx_spi_probe,
        .remove   = xxx_spi_remove,
};
module_spi_driver(xxx_spi_driver);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding i2c client devices on x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64)

Comment: Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817205/2511795 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855157/2511795.

Comment: And there is in-kernel documentation on your topic: https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/enumeration.html#spi-serial-bus-support.