# libgpiod and blink a led (heartbeat)

Tags: x86, gpio, led, heartbeat, libgpiod

Maybe someone advice me how to add led blink (aka simple heartbeat) to following code?
Code is looking for button event on GPIO pin using libgpiod then triggers shutdown (useful for headless SBCs)

```c
/*
 * Monitor external button on GPIO pin, shutdown machine if pressed
 * Uses gpiod events to reduce CPU load
 */

#define SHUTDOWN_CHIP 2
#define SHUTDOWN_LINE 21     // NEO3 pin 23
#define SHUTDOWN_HOLD 3     // seconds to hold down button

#include <gpiod.h>          // sudo apt install libgpiod-dev
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

void shut_down() {
  syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Safe shutdown triggered from GPIO button");
  system("/usr/bin/sudo /bin/gpioset 2 24=0");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct gpiod_chip *chip;
  struct gpiod_line *button;

  void line_release() {
    gpiod_line_release(button);
    gpiod_chip_close(chip);
  }

  chip = gpiod_chip_open_by_number(SHUTDOWN_CHIP);
  button = gpiod_chip_get_line(chip, SHUTDOWN_LINE);
  if (button == NULL) {
    perror("Invalid GPIO chip/pin number");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // Use if your board doesn't use a pullup resistor by default (libgpiod v1.5+)
  // if (gpiod_line_request_both_edges_events_flags(button, "gpio-shutdown", GPIOD_LINE_REQUEST_FLAG_BIAS_PULL_UP) < 0) {
  if (gpiod_line_request_both_edges_events(button, "gpio-shutdown") < 0) {
    perror("Can't claim that GPIO pin (monitor already running?)");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  syslog(LOG_INFO, "Monitoring GPIO button for safe shutdown requests");
  atexit(line_release);

  while (true) {
    if (gpiod_line_event_wait(button, NULL)) {
      struct gpiod_line_event ev;
      struct timespec t_held = {SHUTDOWN_HOLD,0};
      gpiod_line_event_read(button, &ev);
      if (ev.event_type == GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_FALLING_EDGE && !gpiod_line_event_wait(button, &t_held)) {
        shut_down();
      };
    };
  };

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is some thoughts by break a loop by "timeout" option with libgpiod:

```c
int gpiod_line_event_wait(struct gpiod_line *line, const struct timespec *timeout)
```

Comment: Is it for educational purposes? Otherwise it should be done completely differently, i.e. button via `gpio-keys` in-kernel driver, and led via `leds-gpio` and `heartbeat` trigger. These will require properly crafted DTS (Device tree), no C code is needed at all!

Comment: _"You’ve made an LED blink using only a device tree!"_ https://www.leaflabs.com/news/2017/3/7/using-linux-device-trees-for-fun-and-profit There is an example of the functionality of blinking LED.

Comment: x86 PCs don’t use static device trees, they use other mechanisms to enumerate installed hardware (ACPI tables, PCI enumeration, USB...). So you won’t find a corresponding .dtb file in /boot.

Comment: So, you hadn't given even a clue in your Q. Anyway, you may implement the same in ACPI. `heartbeat` LED example: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/blob/master/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples/edison/leds.asli. GPIO button example: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/blob/master/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples/edison/buttons.asli. Some documentation about SSDT overlays: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/acpi/ssdt-overlays.html.

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add `@USER` to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Comment: Also some SO answers for similar topics ("how to create SSDT overlay for xyz"): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817205/2511795, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855157/2511795, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54967620/2511795 (also see other links in the answers).