# How to get data of BH1750 (light sensor) via on I2C interface using i2c-tools

Tags: linux, x86, i2c, light-sensor, upsquared

I am trying to use [BH170FVI sensor](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/bh1750fvi-e-186247.pdf) via on I²C interface on Ubuntu-16.04. My board is [UpSquared](https://up-board.org/upsquared/specifications/) not Raspberry.

To be able to use i2c interface, I installed `i2c-tools`. I also controlled [BMI160 sensor](https://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/_tech/media/datasheets/BST-BMI160-DS000.pdf) with this tool before without meeting a problem.

When I tried to detect my sensor via on terminal with the command:

```sh
i2cdetect -r -y 5
```

This command detects my sensor correctly as shown below:

[image]

As it seems my device adress is `0x23`.

After this when I tried to read all the register map data by the command:

```sh
i2cdump -y -f 5 0x23
```

The result is:

[image]

The problem is all map adresses are zero. At least one of them should read light amount. I thought the sensor power may off but I tried to use command `i2cset` for power-on but still nothing change.

Note: My sensor has no problem because I tried it with Arduino and also with below code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import smbus
import time
 
# Define some constants from the datasheet
DEVICE     = 0x23 # Default device I2C address
POWER_DOWN = 0x00 # No active state
POWER_ON   = 0x01 # Power on
RESET      = 0x07 # Reset data register value
ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE = 0x20
 
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)  # Rev 2 Pi uses 1
 
def convertToNumber(data):
  # Simple function to convert 2 bytes of data
  # into a decimal number
  return ((data[1] + (256 * data[0])) / 1.2)
 
def readLight(addr=DEVICE):
  data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr,ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE)
  return convertToNumber(data)
 
def main():
 
  while True:
    print "Light Level : " + str(readLight()) + " lux"
    time.sleep(0.5)
 
if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

My question is that why I cant control my sensor via on `i2c-tools`.

Comment: Working with sensors from user space like this is a wrong approach to begin with. The correct one is to rely on the kernel driver, in this case: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/light/bh1750.c.

Comment: Since you have ACPI based platform, you need to use SSDT overlay to enable the sensor on your configuration. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768841/building-a-i2c-device-controller and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118721/spidev-linux-driver-on-intel-atom-board

Comment: @0andriy I checked your links but unfortunately I am not so good at with these platforms. All I need is that being able to read sensor data like in Python code I shared. But I need that code in C/C++, when I searched, I understood that I cant use smbus with c/c++ like this. I need a simple c/c++ code like in python code to read the data. [This link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/light/bh1750.c) also I couldnt run cos of many undefined libraries. If you can share a simple code to read the data, I ll accept your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by many undefined libraries? Have you tried to compile it in user space?! No, I'm talking about *using* it in user space, since it's a *kernel* driver. For that `libiio` is needed (of course one may simple do it thru sysfs, though it's not so convenient). Summarize: in-kernel driver (already in upstream) with help of ACPI will bring you an IIO **standard** ABI to user space, where with (optional) help of `libiio` you can get sensor data. This is the way how it should go.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for your suggestions. I am not familiar with these issues and I think its better to start from beginning. Can you advise me a link to begin with about my problem? I checked and tried links above but I couldnt go on because of lack of knowledge. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think [@0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) is right. You need a driver, a library to interface it (more details in the ["official" user documentation for libiio](http://analogdevicesinc.github.io/libiio/)), with python bindings in your case and some configuration. In user space you could use mraa/upm, but it's not in your Ubuntu so you would need to build that.

The suggested answer is to use the driver in the kernel, create a small ACPI table that tells the kernel which device to find on address 0x23 on bus 5. And then you use `python-libiio` or `libiio` C++ bindings to access the device. Examples of ACPI tables that can be loaded into the kernel (hint: through ConfigFS) are here https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/tree/master/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples.

In your case it will be something like:

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("bh1750.aml", "SSDT", 5, "", "BH1750", 1)
{
    External (_SB_.PCI0.I2C5, DeviceObj) // Define Correct I2C controller
    Scope (\_SB.PCI0.I2C5)
    {
        Device (ALS0)
        {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "ROHM BH1750FVI ambient light sensor")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                    I2cSerialBus (
                            0x23,                   // I2C Address
                            ControllerInitiated, 
                            400000,                 // Bus Speed
                            AddressingMode7Bit,     
                            "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C5",
                            0x00,
                            ResourceConsumer,,)
            }
            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"compatible", "rohm,bh1750"},
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

...assuming the path to the controller is `\\_SB_.PCI0.I2C5` (you may find it in DSDT).

The links [@0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) gave in comments, i.e. [adding i2c client devices on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64), [Building a i2c device controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768841/building-a-i2c-device-controller)
 and [spidev Linux driver on Intel Atom board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118721/spidev-linux-driver-on-intel-atom-board) have additional information how to compile and attach the above table to your system.

Comment: if I want to use as mraa/upm, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it is not possible doing that with i2c-tools. The problem is the way you need to read the measurement results from BH1750. See datasheet:

`S Adr Rd (A) (Data) A (Data) NA P`

You cannot create such a sequence with i2c-tools:

- either one byte without register address
- *n* bytes, but you have to provide a register address

Both will result in I2C command sequences which are not what the chip wants.

It worked for me in C from userspace.
See my question here:

[Read a word (2 byte) without providing a register address from userspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69420114/read-a-word-2-byte-without-providing-a-register-address-from-userspace/69595167)