# adding i2c client devices on x86_64

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, acpi

On my x86_64 board, there is i2c-bus coming out of a MFD device. There are devices on to this i2c-bus. I am able to detect these devices using i2cdetect program.

```
# i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 4c -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I need the kernel to detect these devices automatically, So, I tried writing i2c_board_info as in given below code, But still, the kernel is not able to detect these devices automatically.

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>

#define BUS_NUMBER      0

static struct __init i2c_board_info tst_i2c0_board_info[]  = {                   
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("ltc2990", 0x4c),
    },
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("24c128", 0x57),
    },
};

static int tst_i2c_board_setup(void)
{
    int ret=-1;
    ret = i2c_register_board_info(BUS_NUMBER, tst_i2c0_board_info, ARRAY_SIZE(tst_i2c0_board_info));
    return ret;
}
device_initcall(tst_i2c_board_setup);
```

Any suggestions on how can I solve this ?

Comment: does tst_i2c_board_setup() is called after I2C bus 0 registration

Comment: @Ash I did test for both scenarios ie calling before & after bus 0 registration; by changing device_initcall to arch_initcall. It doesnot help

Comment: You need to use ACPI for that. I would answer this with examples after my vacation, for now just google for *meta-acpi* project on Github to get the original idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have an ACPI-enabled platform the best approach is to provide the ASL excerpts for given devices.

Because of Intel Galileo platform for IoT the Atmel 24 series EEPROM has got its own ACPI ID and an excerpt will be simple:

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("at24.aml", "SSDT", 5, "", "AT24", 1)
{
    External (_SB_.PCI0.I2C2, DeviceObj)

    Scope (\_SB.PCI0.I2C2)
    {
        Device (EEP0) {
            Name (_HID, "INT3499")
            Name (_DDN, "Atmel AT24 compatible EEPROM")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                I2cSerialBusV2 (
                    0x0057,              // I2C Slave Address
                    ControllerInitiated,
                    400000,              // Bus speed
                    AddressingMode7Bit,
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C2",   // Link to ACPI I2C host controller
                    0
                )
            })

            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"size", 1024},
                    Package () {"pagesize", 32},
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the *size* property is being added in a <s>[pending patch](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg1484199.html)</s> series (patches [add eeprom "size" property](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f2f5afd3845) and [add support to fetch eeprom device property "size"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=dbc1ab9c1250)).

Note, the address width is 8-bit as hard coded for now. In case you need to have 16-bit you need to create a similar patches as mentioned above.

For LTC2990 power monitor you need the following excerpt:

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("ltc2990.aml", "SSDT", 5, "", "PMON", 1)
{
    External (\_SB_.PCI0.I2C2, DeviceObj)

    Scope (\_SB.PCI0.I2C2)
    {
        Device (PMON)
        {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "Linear Technology LTC2990 power monitor")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                I2cSerialBus (
                    0x4c,                   // Bus address
                    ControllerInitiated,    // Don't care
                    400000,                 // Fast mode (400 kHz)
                    AddressingMode7Bit,     // 7-bit addressing
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C2",      // I2C host controller
                    0                       // Must be 0
                )
            })

            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"compatible", "lltc,ltc2990"},
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Note, unfortunately there is no compatible string in the driver, so, one needs to add it like [it's done here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-iio/msg34380.html).

In the examples above `\\_SB.PCI0.I2C2` is an absolute path to the I2C host controller.

How to get those files applied:

- first of all, create a folder

```shell
mkdir -p kernel/firmware/acpi
```

- save files under names mentioned in the `DefinitionBlock()` macro in that folder
- create the uncompressed cpio archive and concatenate the original initrd on top:

```shell
find kernel | cpio -H newc --create > /boot/instrumented_initrd
cat /boot/initrd >> /boot/instrumented_initrd
```

More details are available in [SSDT Overlays](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/acpi/ssdt-overlays.html).

The other examples and description of the idea behind can be found on [meta-acpi GitHub page](https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/), some materials from which are copied here.

Comment: What if I do not want to use initrd. I am directly loading kernel from GRUB. In such a scenario, how can I apply those files? Can you please help.

Comment: @InsaneCoder, another way is to upload them via configfs. See this link: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/acpi/ssdt-overlays.txt (here is the patch that brought it https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9221305/)

Answer (score 0):

After going through [Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices), I understand there are several methods to do the same(e.g. as *0andriy* suggested usng acpi table etc), I used "i2c_new_probed_device" method. Below is the used code :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>

#define BUS_NUMBER      0
#define NUM_DEVICE      2

static const unsigned short normal_i2c[][2] = {
    {0x4c, I2C_CLIENT_END},
    {0x57, I2C_CLIENT_END},
};

static struct i2c_board_info tst_i2c0_board_info[2] = {
        {I2C_BOARD_INFO("ltc2990", 0x4c), },
        {I2C_BOARD_INFO("24c128", 0x57), },
};

static int tst_i2c_board_setup(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct i2c_adapter *i2c_adap;

    i2c_adap = i2c_get_adapter(BUS_NUMBER);
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_DEVICE; i++)
        i2c_new_probed_device(i2c_adap, &tst_i2c0_board_info[i],
                           normal_i2c[i], NULL);
    i2c_put_adapter(i2c_adap);

    return 0;
}
late_initcall(tst_i2c_board_setup);
```

Comment: While it's working, this is an abuse of ACPI-enabled platforms.

Comment: I agree, This is fixed in haste. I shall use ACPI based method.