# How can we define SPI devices on x86?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi, acpi

I want to read data from CAN bus and for that I am using MPC2515 (as a CAN Conroller) via SPI.
Working on Up Board 2 based on Ubilinux (Linux kernel version is 4.9.45), its architecture x86 doesn't use device-tree entries like ARM for example. So how can I define SPI device settings?

Comment: You can find some tips in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64/