# Integrating NXP PN7150 driver and device info into Android x86 kernel, where should device info go?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to integrate the NXP 7150 drivers into Android P for an x86 based platform.

Here are the integration guidelines given : https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11690.pdf

Since x86 does not support device tree as of now, I need to use the Platform data. But I am not sure in which file should I place this info :

```
static struct pn544_i2c_platform_data nfc_pdata = {
.irq_gpio = GPIO_TO_PIN(1,29),
.ven_gpio = GPIO_TO_PIN(0,30),
.firm_gpio = GPIO_UNUSED
.clkreq_gpio = GPIO_UNUSED
};
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata nfc_board_info[] = {
{
I2C_BOARD_INFO("pn547", 0x28),
.platform_data = &nfc_pdata,
},
};
```

I have minimal driver development knowledge, hence I am not able to figure out. I have built the driver as a builtin module. I understand that I need to plug the PN7150 dongle and then put the device info somewhere in the kernel code, which can call the probe of the driver on boot up. Please help.

Comment: You can either add it inside your board file or you can add a new kernel module and then export 7150 driver module from there.

Comment: @vinodmaverick : I see an example here : https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Linux-Device-Drivers-Development/tree/master/Chapter05 where just the .name has to match in order for the driver to get probed.

But I am still confused as what could be the way to encode `nfc_board_info` and then probe the driver? Can you please put some dummy code snippet as an answer to this ?

Comment: Use ACPI for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64/46370798#46370798

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding i2c client devices on x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64)

Answer (score -1):

As I told in my comment as well; but if you don't have any board file (which I am assuming is not available in your `X86` Arch code) then you can simply make a new kernel modul. Inside the init function of kernel module you can register your `I2C` device info:

```
static int __init dummy_nfc_init(void) {

i2c_register_board_info(1, nfc_board_info,
            ARRAY_SIZE(nfc_board_info));
}

module_init(dummy_nfc_init);
```

In the example while registering the board info **1** is `I2C` bus number. In your case you need to modify the bus number. You can make this dummy driver as built-in. So when your PN7150 driver **`.-name`** will matched with **`I2C_BOARD_INFO`** name **`"pn547"`** driver `probe` function will get called while for other callback function and `read/write` operation slave address **`0x28`** and **`I2C`** bus number should matched.

Comment: Oh, no, don't do like this.